# DT datatable background colour black, but still have hover and selection colours

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am new to using the `DT` library in R and the `datatable()` function and would like some help on how to make changes to the way it looks...

I currently have a black background for a datatable and would like it to change colour on hovering over it, or when specific rows are selected...but choosing a background seems to eliminate the hover options...any help would be much appreciated.

Please see the below to see how far I got with trying to make the black background table with hover.

```
DT:::datatable(
  head(iris, 20),rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom='t',
    initComplete = JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
      "}")
  ),
  container = tags$table(
    class="stripe row-border hover",
    tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(colnames(iris), tags$th)))
  )
) %>% formatStyle(columns=colnames(iris),color='white',background = 'black')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use

```
shiny_0.13.2 
DT_0.1.55
```

1)You need `target="row"` in `formatStyle`

2) If you use it in `shiny` you can simply add  !important to hover css :

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover {
                              background-color: #9c4242 !important;
                              } "))),
    DT::dataTableOutput("tt")
    )
  )

server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$tt=DT::renderDataTable(
    DT:::datatable(
      head(iris, 20),rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom='t',
                                                     initComplete = JS(
                                                       "function(settings, json) {",
                                                       "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                                       "}")
      ),
      container = tags$table(
        class="stripe row-border hover",
        tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(colnames(iris), tags$th)))
      )
    ) %>% formatStyle(columns=colnames(iris),color='white',background = 'black',target = 'row')
  )
})


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

*note, this work only in shiny*

## Update not shiny version

try to add important into callback

```
library(DT)
library(shiny) # needed for tags
    DT:::datatable(
      head(iris, 20),rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom='t',
                                                     initComplete = JS(
                                                       "function(settings, json) {",
                                                       "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                                       "var css = document.createElement('style');
                                                        css.type = 'text/css';
                                                        css.innerHTML = '.table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover { background-color: #9c4242 !important }';
                                                        document.body.appendChild(css);",
                                                       "}")
      ),
      container = tags$table(
        class="stripe row-border hover",
        tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(colnames(iris), tags$th)))
      )
    ) %>% formatStyle(columns=colnames(iris),color='white',background = 'black',target = 'row')
```

## Update 2 invert color

for pretty look you can use

css

```
table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover { -webkit-filter: invert(100%);filter: invert(100%)  }
```

Comment: Not sure if you have finished writing your answer, but neither the shiny code or the non-shiny version work...in terms of changing colour upon hovering or changing when clicking...(fyi i ran your shiny code using the following...`runApp(shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server))`)

Comment: Non shiny version work only hover, in your app work nothing?( which version of DT)

Comment: Ah the shiny version works now...i was using DT v0.1 , how do you include the css for the shiny version?

Comment: Not fully undertand what you mean, but run app see inspect in browser + add hover to row ... see that some of css not used .. copy that css to `tags$head(tags$style(HTML(` and add important  ( or ` -webkit-filter: invert(100%);filter: invert(100%) for simply create invert color for hover `)

Comment: Ah I see, i thought the css was put in as a separate file...what you wrote makes sense now! Thank you!

Comment: How would I go about changing the control colours? i.e. i have now set `dom='ltp'` and would like the `table-control-color` to be white...where would i adjust my code for that? I think i need to change this as is suggested here: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator

Comment: I dont know what your means "table-control-color" but length menu control you can change using `.dataTables_length>label>select {}` (css).... page button - `.paginate_button` ( you can see it in inspect at your browser)